# Вложенные кавычки в строке Питона

Tags: python, синтаксис

Каков полный список способов, которыми в Питоне можно записать строку, содержащую вложенные кавычки?

```
quote = "\""
```

Answer (score 7):

Используя escape-последовательности:

```
quote = "\""
quote = "\42"
quote = "\x22"
```

Используя одинарные кавычки:

```
quote = '"'
```

Используя тройные кавычки:

```
quote = \
"""
"
"""
```

Comment: Тройные одинарные кавычки забыли

Comment: Самый частые: `'"'` или `"\""`. А так много ещё способов можно напридумывать, например, `chr(0x22)`, `u"\u0022"`, `html.unescape("&quot;")`, etc