# Python распознавание спец-символа "

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пожалуйста помогите распознаванию спецсимвола " в Python

```
u = input("") 
l=""

if u[0:5] == "print":
    for y in u[5:]:
        if  y == "(" or  y == ")" or y == """:
            None
        else:
            l+=str(y)
print(f"{l}")
```

Как сделать  если будет написано " не выводит символ, но пайтон думает что " это символ код и выводит ошибку

Comment: Просьба все же грамотнее стараться писать. Если русский -  не родной, то, возможно, через GoogleTranslate с проверкой, что получилось. Очень сложночитаемо.

Comment: @Сергей да ладно, это нормально читается, в отличие от дореформенного стиля) Проще самому поправить.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Вложенные кавычки в строке Питона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423/1365)

Comment: @insolor Жалко там ответ не принятый

Comment: @CrazyEif уже принял

Comment: @CrazyElf, это не так уж важно (с исторической точки зрения). В принципе это важно только для автора вопроса и автора ответа. Николас - основатель ХэшКода, Станислав - скорее всего сооснователь, т.к. он автор вопроса №1: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"\""
```

или

```
'"'
```